# Remove Google Apps mini and install another version - LineageOS

Tags: installation, twrp, google-play-services, uninstallation, lineageos

I have installed LineageOS 14.1 (+TWRP) on Samsung S5 g900f (klte) with Google Apps mini. I followed this guide: 
https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/klte/install

I also added Google Apps Mini zip during the installation phase.

**Question:**
Is there a way to remove Google Apps mini and install Google Apps nano (or pico) package? (Without reinstalling from scratch)

Regards

Comment: Flashing the LOS package again (to restore `/system` to a clean state) then flashing the GAPPS you need should be sufficient - I don't see a need to do a factory reset here. Of course, do a nandroid backup as always.

Comment: I'm never flashing GApps – but AFAIK the OpenGApps "flashables" perform a cleanup as first step. Apart from that, I'd second what @AndyYan pointed out.

Comment: @global_warming GApps are installed on the `/system` permission – which a [tag:factory-reset] never touches. So the way you've put it (as only criterion) it makes no sense.

Comment: Thankyou, @AndyYan and others, by falshing LOS again.. is it going to loss all the installed apps and local configurations? Or are there preserved?

Comment: Everything's preserved unless you do a factory reset manually.

Comment: @AndyYan If you copy your previous comments in an asnwer I'll accept it. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flashing the LOS package again (to restore `/system` to a clean state) then flashing the GAPPS you need should be sufficient - no need to do a factory reset. Of course, do a nandroid backup as always just to be safe.